# Google Sheets countunique + query + importrange = syntax error

Tags: google-sheets

```
=countunique(query({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suCxx5n9KafFT8aIpS8VDWQdTbquepR9z5U099mlkNE/edit#gid=1167025375";"C1300:F3000"});"select col1 where col3 = '"PRI"' & col4 = '"A165"' "))
```

In the result - syntax error. Why?

Access is given. A165 is a cell of importing table.

Comment: just try each element separately to isolate which part is not working also I though it should be written like "select col1 where col3 = 'PRI' and col4 = 'A165' "

Comment: =COUNTUNIQUE(QUERY({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suCxx5n9KafFT8aIpS8VDWQdTbquepR9z5U099mlkNE/edit#gid=1167025375";"C1300:F3000")};"SELECT Col1")) works, but when I add Where Col3 contain 'PRI' counts only 1, when there are more than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Col1` instead of `col1`

`)};` instead of `});`

`'PRI'` instead of `"'PRI'"`

`and` instead of `&`

also add sheet name to `C1300:F3000`

try:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(
 "1suCxx5n9KafFT8aIpS8VDWQdTbquepR9z5U099mlkNE"; "C1300:F3000")};
 "select Col1 
  where Col3 = 'PRI' 
    and Col4 = '"&A165&"'"))
```

Comment: =countunique(query({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suCxx5n9KafFT8aIpS8VDWQdTbquepR9z5U099mlkNE/edit#gid=1167025375";"Запросы КЗ/Азия стандарт/сборка!C1300:F3000")};
  "select Col1 ")) - even like this counts only 1.

Comment: @artyomvasilevskiy did you **allow access** by running `=importrange("1suCxx5n9KafFT8aIpS8VDWQdTbquepR9z5U099mlkNE"; Азия стандарт/сборка!C1")` first in any cell?

Comment: Yes, access is allowed for the whole table.

Comment: =COUNTUNIQUE(QUERY({importrange("docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…)};"SELECT Col1")) works, but when I add Where Col3 contain 'PRI' counts only 1, when there are more than 1

Comment: @artyomvasilevskiy can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u7vI5kSTMRavLdAgo0t-A7xzAMHU1A9ffkWohMvWi-A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @artyomvasilevskiy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16MWz28rAkMlSybytMduYBYTDX2zMN64SBiYD8M-lSN8/edit#gid=0

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was in A165 cell, content of the cell the same, but format is different. THX A LOT!

Answer (score 1):

Your formula:

```
=countunique(query({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suCxx5n9KafFT8aIpS8VDWQdTbquepR9z5U099mlkNE/edit#gid=1167025375";"C1300:F3000"});
  "select col1 where col3 = '"PRI"' & col4 = '"A165"' "))
```

Corrected formula:

```
=countunique(query({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suCxx5n9KafFT8aIpS8VDWQdTbquepR9z5U099mlkNE/edit#gid=1167025375";"C1300:F3000")};
  "select col1 where col3 = 'PRI' & col4 = '" & A165 & "' "))
```

This required "&" (ampersands) between the text strings - assuming contents of A165 is a string - at the end of your formula, and changed `"})"` to `")}"` before the select.  You needed to close off the IMPORTRANGE function before closing the array with "}".

If A165 has a numeric value, you must remove the single quotes.

```
& col4 = " & A165 & "))
```

Also removed double quotes around PRI.
From
`col3 = '"PRI"'`
to
`col3 = 'PRI'`

Comment: Syntax error disappeared, but it doesn't count properly, instead 400+ only 1.